# How to set librarian options of the kind /ignore:4221 for visual studio 2010 with CMake?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cmake, warnings

I have LNK warnings that I want to disable during my C++ project's compilation. I am using visual studio 2010. The warning appears during the compilation of some libraries and of my final executable.

I know exactly how to disable these warnings in Visual Studio:

1. for the executable: I open its Properties (with a right click on its solution explorer entry); then I choose Linker -> Command Line, and then I add /ignore:4221 as an additional option
2. for the library: I open its Properties (as for the executable); then I select "Configuration Properties", then Librarian -> Command Line, and there I add /ignore:4221 as additional option.

Now, I would like to automate this process with CMake, because I have hundreds of libraries and executables which I want to customize this way. For the executable, I think I have found the solution: it seems to work when I add in each CMake project the line

```
LIST(APPEND CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "/ignore:4221")
```

in its root CMakeLists.txt. I haven't found how to do the very same for the librarian. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be set like

```
set(CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS} /IGNORE:4221")
```